# Whenever I make changes to a view in Drupal 7 I get this error?

Tags: drupal, module, view

My views module does this annoying thing whenever I try to save changes. It flashes and produces a screen of garbled text. I have to click on the back button to get back to the edit screen. The changes I made are saved but this is obviously not ideal way to work with the views module. Is my module corrupt? Thanks.

Comment: I would post images, but I'm new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have used the latest version of jQuery to your Drupal install & thats why you are facing this problem.

You can do two things - either you roll back to shipped jQuery version of Drupal or use [this](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module for updated jQuery & I hope your problem will be solved. I solved my problem with same method..